# Using base ifelse with conditions

Tags: r

One of my condition is: if Availability == "Not Available", it will automatically be a Cat A under the Categories column. However when i use the == "Not Available", it will only print out the default value from newdf$Options and when i use != "Available", it print out my intended output. I can't seem to figure out why the == "Not Available" does not work.

My other condition is: if CatBCol appear in Colour, it will automatically be Cat B under the Options and the rest will be Cat A.

```
CatACol<-c("Black","Brown","Maroon")
CatBCol<- c("Orange","Pink")

newdf <- setDT(df)[ ,paste0("Colour", 1:2) := tstrsplit(df$Colour, ",",  type.convert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)]
newdf$Options <- ifelse((newdf$Colour1 %in% CatBCol), "Cat B",ifelse((newdf$Colour2 %in% CatBCol),"Cat B", "Cat A"))
newdf$Categories <- ifelse((newdf$Availability == "Not Available"), "Cat A", newdf$Options)
```

Intended output:

```
         Colour   Availability Colour1 Colour2 Options Categories
1:        Black      Available   Black    <NA>   Cat A      Cat A
2:        Brown Not Available    Brown    <NA>   Cat A      Cat A
3:       Maroon Not Available   Maroon    <NA>   Cat A      Cat A
4:       Orange      Available  Orange    <NA>   Cat B      Cat B
5:         Pink      Available    Pink    <NA>   Cat B      Cat B
6:   Black,Pink      Available   Black    Pink   Cat B      Cat B
7: Brown,Orange Not Available    Brown  Orange   Cat B      Cat A
8:  Maroon,Pink      Available  Maroon    Pink   Cat B      Cat B
```

Actual output:

```
         Colour   Availability Colour1 Colour2 Options Categories
1:        Black      Available   Black    <NA>   Cat A      Cat A
2:        Brown Not Available    Brown    <NA>   Cat A      Cat A
3:       Maroon Not Available   Maroon    <NA>   Cat A      Cat A
4:       Orange      Available  Orange    <NA>   Cat B      Cat B
5:         Pink      Available    Pink    <NA>   Cat B      Cat B
6:   Black,Pink      Available   Black    Pink   Cat B      Cat B
7: Brown,Orange Not Available    Brown  Orange   Cat B      Cat B
8:  Maroon,Pink      Available  Maroon    Pink   Cat B      Cat B
```

My data frame

```
structure(list(Colour = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 
6L), .Label = c("Black", "Black,Pink", "Brown", "Brown,Orange", 
"Maroon", "Maroon,Pink", "Orange", "Pink"), class = "factor"), 
    Availability = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Available", "Not Available "), class = "factor"), 
    Colour1 = c("Black", "Brown", "Maroon", "Orange", "Pink", 
    "Black", "Brown", "Maroon"), Colour2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Pink", "Orange", "Pink")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002a5fdbc1ef0>)
```

Comment: Notice in your `dput` that is has the levels specified as `.Label = c("Available", "Not Available ")` or you can run `levels(df$Availability)`. Notice how there is a space after the e in "Not Available ". Someone that extra space got in there. That means when you do an exact equals and don't have that extra space in your string, then it won't match.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice the extra space in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the whitespace with `trimws`. Also you can use `fcase` (or `case_when` in `dplyr`) to include multiple `ifelse` conditions.

```
library(data.table)
newdf[, Availability := trimws(Availability)]

newdf[, Categories := fcase(Availability == 'Not Available', 'Cat A', 
                            Colour1 %in% CatBCol | Colour2 %in% CatBCol, 'Cat B', 
                            default = 'Cat A')]

newdf
#         Colour  Availability Colour1 Colour2 Categories
#1:        Black     Available   Black    <NA>      Cat A
#2:        Brown Not Available   Brown    <NA>      Cat A
#3:       Maroon Not Available  Maroon    <NA>      Cat A
#4:       Orange     Available  Orange    <NA>      Cat B
#5:         Pink     Available    Pink    <NA>      Cat B
#6:   Black,Pink     Available   Black    Pink      Cat B
#7: Brown,Orange Not Available   Brown  Orange      Cat A
#8:  Maroon,Pink     Available  Maroon    Pink      Cat B
```

Comment: I faced this error after running the code.                    `Error in fcase(Availability == "Not Available", "Cat A", Colour1 %in%  : 
  could not find function "fcase`

Comment: I tried using the case_when function                                   `newdf[, Categories := case_when(Availability == 'Not Available'~ 'Cat A', 
                            Colour1 %in% CatBCol | Colour2 %in% CatBCol, ~ 'Cat B', 
                            TRUE ~ 'Cat A')]`                                   I came across this error                                            
`Error: Case 2 (`Availability == "Not Available" ~ "Cat A"`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector`

Comment: `fcase` is available in the latest version of `data.table`. Try to install it with `install.packages('data.table')` and load `data.table` and try again.

Comment: I have `data.table` 1.13.0. BTW I just tried this `case_when` code and it worked for me. `newdf[, Categories := case_when(Availability == 'Not Available'~ 'Cat A', 
                            Colour1 %in% CatBCol | Colour2 %in% CatBCol~ 'Cat B', 
                            TRUE ~ 'Cat A')]`

Comment: version 1.12.8? install.packages("data.table") data.table::update.dev.pkg() I updated it using this code and run it again but I still face the same error

Comment: @MuhdHannan I have `data.table` `1.13.0`. Did you check the `case_when` answer in the above comment?

Comment: I just realised that there was a comma between CatBCol and ~ in my original code. Thank you, but the output is not the same as my intended output. I guess I'll have to stick to what I have at the moment.

Comment: What is different? It should be the same. Did you run the `trimws` code? `newdf[, Availability := trimws(Availability)]`

Comment: MY BAD, I ran a different code....Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try use the grave symbol ***inside*** the quotes. Looks like this `

It's next to the 1 key on your keyboard.

When referring to variable names with spaces we must also wrap the variable name inside a set of grave accent marks.

Alternatively, if your availability column is character convert it to factor.
Or convert it to 0's and 1's, and set it to numeric. Do your calculations and then convert it to your desired strings at the final stage of your process.